# Backbone scope of window instead of this

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope

Why is this logging as window instead of the Backbone object?

```
App.Models.Site = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'assets/json/app.json',

    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch({success:this.success});
    },

    success: function(){
        console.log('success', this.attributes); // log's: success undefined
        console.log(this); // window
    }
});
```

Comment: Normally, you can just pass the context as a parameter: http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this, however not in `this` :) case.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function is called by jQuery's (or whichever DOM lib you use) `ajax` function.

Use `this.fetch({success:_.bind(this.success, this)});`

Comment: Not quite, Backbone puts a success handler between you and jQuery, that success handler calls the passed to `fetch`, hence the Backbone specific arguments: ["Accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash, which are passed `(model, response, options)` and `(model, xhr, options)` as arguments, respectively."](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch).

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to bind `this` in your initialize function like that:

```
App.Models.Site = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'assets/json/app.json',

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'success'); // Ensure the 'success' method has the correct 'this'
        this.fetch({success:this.success});
    },

    success: function(){
        console.log('success', this.attributes);
        console.log(this); // this is now correctly set
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"this" in the success attribute of your fetch function is not in your backbone view scope anymore. A workaround is to add a

```
var that = this;
```

And use "that" in your fetch success attribute like below:

```
var that = this;
this.fetch({success: that.success});
```